# Nix permission error when installing local Idris library

Tags: idris, nix

I installed Idris2 v0.4.0 with

```
$ nix-env -i idris2
```

and that works fine. I can launch the REPL and type check my program, but I'm having difficulty installing a local Idris library. I get

```
$ idris2 --install foo.ipkg
...
Uncaught error: INTERNAL ERROR: Can't make directory /nix/store/...-idris2-0.4.0/idris2-0.4.0/foo-0.0.1
Permission Denied
```

I assume this is because Idris doesn't have permission to install to `/nix`.

What I've tried

- set the `IDRIS2_PREFIX` to be local, but then Idris can't find the Prelude (as expected, since I've told it to look elsewhere).
- using `sudo`, but that not only doesn't work (it doesn't recognise `idris2`), it also seems massive overkill for a library install

Answer (score 1):

As of writing, Idris 2 is not supported [properly](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/119175) in Nixpkgs. Some discussion and experimental work [is going on](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/issues/1307).

Answer (score 0):

If I use homebrew to install Idris rather than Nix, with

```
brew install idris2
```

it works fine.